# Encoding error on scraping pages with special characters using R packages

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have been scraping web pages using `httr` and storing the results in a data.frame, `df`
e.g

```
library(httr)
urlPage <-"http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/cartoon/2014/aug/04/ben-jennings-cartoon-first-world-war-centenary"
pagehtml <- content(GET(urlPage),"parsed")
title <- xpathSApply(pagehtml, "//*/div[@id='main-article-info']/h1", xmlValue)
```

This example leads to a value in the `df$title` variables of
"Ben Jennings on the centenary of the first world war â\u0080\u0093Â cartoon"

I now realize I can avoid this problem with special characters by a different approach

```
library(XML)
pagehtml <- htmlParse(urlPage, isURL = TRUE,encoding='UTF-8')
title <- xpathSApply(pagehtml, "//*/div[@id='main-article-info']/h1", xmlValue)
```

which results in a desired outcome of "Ben Jennings on the centenary of the first world war – cartoon"

So I know what to do from now on but wish to correct the data I have already collected. I have tried

```
Encoding(title) <-"UTF-8"
```

but that no effect

Any help much appreciated

Edited in response to request using the bad_title and good_title respectvely. On my windows machine

```
charToRaw(good_title)
 [1] 42 65 6e 20 4a 65 6e 6e 69 6e 67 73 20 6f 6e 20 74 68 65 20 63 65 6e 74 65 6e 61     72 79 20 6f 66
[33] 20 74 68 65 20 66 69 72 73 74 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 20 77 61 72 20 e2 80 93 c2 a0 63 61 72 74 6f 6f
[65] 6e

charToRaw(bad_title)
 [1] 42 65 6e 20 4a 65 6e 6e 69 6e 67 73 20 6f 6e 20 74 68 65 20 63 65 6e 74 65 6e 61 72 79 20 6f 66
[33] 20 74 68 65 20 66 69 72 73 74 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 20 77 61 72 20 c3 a2 c2 80 c2 93 c3 82 c2 a0 63
[65] 61 72 74 6f 6f 6e
```

Comment: Do you mean `Encoding(df$title)` <- "UTF-8"?

Comment: Give `rawToChar(charToRaw(iconv(title, from="UTF-8", to="latin1")))` a go on your existing data.

Comment: @Pascal - either really

Comment: @hrbrmstr tx for suggestion That results in "Ben Jennings on the centenary of the first world war â€“Â cartoon" so different but not the answer. The reverse does not work either

Comment: But what are your locales `Sys.getlocale()`?

Comment: @Pascal "LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252"

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to be a very messy problem. So, just to make sure we're looking at the exact same bytes, these are the representations I got with your data

```
title_good <- enc2utf8(rawToChar(as.raw(c(0x42, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4a, 0x65, 
0x6e, 0x6e, 0x69, 
0x6e, 0x67, 0x73, 0x20, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x74, 0x68, 0x65, 0x20, 
0x63, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x72, 0x79, 0x20, 0x6f, 
0x66, 0x20, 0x74, 0x68, 0x65, 0x20, 0x66, 0x69, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 
0x20, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x20, 0x77, 0x61, 0x72, 0x20, 
0xe2, 0x80, 0x93, 0xc2, 0xa0, 0x63, 0x61, 0x72, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x6f, 
0x6e))))

title_bad <- enc2utf8(rawToChar(as.raw(c(0x42, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4a, 0x65, 
0x6e, 0x6e, 0x69, 
0x6e, 0x67, 0x73, 0x20, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x74, 0x68, 0x65, 0x20, 
0x63, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x72, 0x79, 0x20, 0x6f, 
0x66, 0x20, 0x74, 0x68, 0x65, 0x20, 0x66, 0x69, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 
0x20, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x20, 0x77, 0x61, 0x72, 0x20, 
0xc3, 0xa2, 0xc2, 0x80, 0xc2, 0x93, 0xc3, 0x82, 0xc2, 0xa0, 0x63, 
0x61, 0x72, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x6e))))
```

So the problem was the the data was actually encoded as UTF-8 but the parser assumed it was ISO-8859-1 and then it was translated to UTF-8. You can re-create the bad version from the good version with

```
iconv(title_good, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8")
# [1] "Ben Jennings on the centenary of the first world war â\u0080\u0093Â cartoon"
```

So the problem is that during the conversion, new bytes are created in a way that doesn't seem to be reversible through the manipulation of encoding. I could not find the exact code that `iconv` was using, but from the test data you supplied, it seems to split up the larger character codes >= 128 into multi-byte codes that do not translate correctly to UTF codes. If we look at the bits of data in a binary representation, basically it seemed to translate via

```
AABB BBBB  ->  1100 00AA  10BB BBBB
```

where AA and BBBBBB are sequences of 1's and 0's

Heres a function that seems to reverse the process

```
revenc<-function(x) {
    cc <- as.numeric(charToRaw(x))
    w<-matrix(which(cc>=128), byrow=T, ncol=2)
    nc<-apply(w, 1, function(x) {bitwShiftL(bitwAnd(cc[x[1]], 3), 6) +
        bitwAnd(cc[x[2]], 63)})
    pp<-rawToChar(as.raw(c(cc[-w], nc)[order(c(seq_along(cc)[-w], w[,1]))]))
    Encoding(pp)<-"UTF-8"
    pp
}

revenc(title_bad)
# [1] "Ben Jennings on the centenary of the first world war – cartoon"
```

Comment: Thanks v much for this. However, running the function on the title_bad string results in " "Ben Jennings on the centenary of the first world war â€“Â cartoon" for me

Comment: I tried forcing my examples to UTF-8. I see that you must be running windows or something where UTF-8 is not the default. Does my title_bad exactly match the bytes of yours?

Comment: Yes sorry I should have mention I am using Windows

Comment: From your two above title_good is "Ben Jennings on the centenary of the first world war â€“Â cartoon" (so not good for me). title_bad is "Ben Jennings on the centenary of the first world war Ã¢Â€Â“Ã‚Â cartoon". That iconv does not work, presumably as you would now expects and results in "Ben Jennings on the centenary of the first world war Ã¢â\u0082¬â\u0080\u009cÃ\u0082Â cartoon"

Comment: As far as I know, there is no UTF-8 locale on Windows. And you should substitute CP1252 to ISO-8859-1 in `iconv`.

Comment: @pssguy I guess I'll have to try on my windows machine tomorrow. But it would help if you could add the results of `charToRaw` for your good and bad values to your original question.

Comment: @Pascal. Not sure if this is relevant but the htmlParse(urlPage, isURL = TRUE,encoding='UTF-8') works fine

Comment: @pssguy Just FYI. I agree I am not sure it is relevant for your problem. But I suspect it might have an impact. This problem won't occurs on Linux or Mac.

Comment: @Pascal. I'd like to help frame the question better but am a bit out of my depth. Applying rawToChar to either my original outcome or the htmlParse result gives me the error "argument 'x' must be a raw vector"

Comment: @pssguy use `charToRaw` on your values, not `rawToChar`

Comment: @pssguy OK. It turns out I just needed to change the last line where I was trying to get the encoding improperly. I have tested this on a windows machine and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks I have just drowned my computer so cannot confirm. Presumably works for any such string